# How to set caret position in extJS tagfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a tagfield and I want to set caret position in tagfield. After selecting few values caret is going down so I want to set at specific position. Here is what I am trying, can anybody please explain me how to do that.

```
expand:function(field,eOpts){
        var field = arguments[0];
        var fieldValue = field.getValue();
        fieldValue.toString().length;
        var pos =  140;//fieldValue.toString().length + 30;
        var el = field.inputEl.dom;
        el.setAttribute("selStartPos",pos);
        if (typeof(el.selectionStart) === "number") {
            el.focus();
            el.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        }
    },
```

Comment: What do you mean by "caret is going down". This is not clear.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Please check this fiddler https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20c8 For fourth tag caret is going to next line. I want caret  should be in first line.

Comment: Does 'caret' mean cursor? If so, there is width specified for the panel which contains the tagfield and after selecting three values. The tagfield expands to its maximum available space horizontally which is panel's width. Later it is expanding in the downward direction. So if the panel width maximized or commented then it works fine.

Comment: @AnandSingh Completely agree with you, tagfield expands to its maximum available space horizontally. And that is fine because this how tagfield work. But I want my cursor or caret to display there. After selection it may come down that is fine. Since I have limited space so I am using `growMAx : 10`, If I remove then things are fine.

Comment: It seems like the the cursor automatically moves down if there is less space available in first line of tagfield and expands downwards irrespective of the options available in the tagfield.

Comment: @AnandSingh Yes It automatically moves down. I want to stay in same line if having any spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor is wrapped in an input element that has a specific width (128px in our example).

[image: tag field input element width]

If at the end of the trigger field, there is less space left than the width of the input element, it will jump to the next line.

We can tweak the input's width via css so that it will take a minimum amount of space and it will stay next to the last selected item.

```
.x-tagfield-input-field {
    width: 3px;
}
.x-tagfield .x-tagfield-input {
    margin: 0;
}
```

One *HUGE DOWNSIDE* of this approach is that you will not really be able to view the text you have typed to filter the items. But it will work fine if the items are directly selected from the dropdown.

Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20nd

**NOTE**: the trigger field should have a "minWidth" or "anchor" config specified, otherwise, it will have a minuscular initial width

Comment: Thanks for answer. +1 Yes It is working correctly. Only typed item is not coming. Let me figure out some solution for that.

Comment: I fixed many issue in and things are working fine. One quick question is There any way by which I can change `.x-tagfield-input-field {
    width: 3px;
}` programmatically. I mean initialy I want this `50px` and afterselection firstelement `20px`. IS that possible ?

Comment: Sure! The tagfield has a reference to the input element, so that you can change intput's width dynamically like so: `tagfield.inputEl.setWidth(300)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Please check [this fiddler](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20c8). For fourth tag caret is going to next line. I want caret should be in first line.

This is intended behavior. The tagfield leaves alway blank space at the end for the next tag to be added. If there is not enough space to expand the tagfield to the right, it expands down by adding a new line.

If you want to be able to add more tags on the same line, just remove the width attribute from the panel.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Sci-Fi Television',
    height: 200,
    //width: 500,
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Ya I know this intend behavior but is there any way by which I can put caret there. Once I type then It go to next line is fine for me.